# Combining tables while changing id - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to create a search function in different tables using UNION and what happened is that the id's are duplicating making the search go wrong. How can I merge different tables into one while no id's are in common?

Here is the example

table1

```
id    name    desc
1     henry   post
2     albert  doth
3     jun     cloth
```

table2

```
id    name    desc
1     kin     revenge
2     pot     eve
```

The result SHOULD be like this

```
id    name    desc
1     henry   post
2     albert  doth
3     jun     cloth
4     kin     revenge
5     pot     eve
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: How do you decide what the new id's are? Must table 2 always continue after all table1 id's are listed?

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using `Sql-Server` <> `MySql`

Comment: @StuartLC It can be. I'm searching from 6 tables to be precise.

Comment: @NoDisplayName Mysql. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you would add a new id using the ANSI standard `row_number()` function:

```
select row_number() over (order by which, id) as newid, name, description
from (select 1 as which, t1.* from table1 t1 union all
      select 2 as which, t2.* from table2 t2
     ) t;
```

Note that `desc` is a really bad name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword and usually a reserved word.

EDIT:

MySQL doesn't support this ANSI standard functionality.  Instead, use variables:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as newid, name, description
from (select 1 as which, t1.* from table1 t1 union all
      select 2 as which, t2.* from table2 t2
     ) t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) vars
order by which, id;
```

I've include the `order by` so the rows remain in the same order that you seem to want them in -- rows from the first table followed by rows from the second table.  If you don't care about the order, just drop the `order by`.

For SQLite, the calculation is much more painful:

```
with cte as (
      select 1 as which, t1.* from table1 t1 union all
      select 2 as which, t2.* from table2 t2
     ) 
select (select count(*)
        from cte cte2
        where cte2.which < cte.which or (ct2.which = cte.which and cte2.id <= cte.id
       ) as id,
       name, description
from cte;
```

Comment: How can I do it using SQLite?

Comment: You have explicitly said that the database you are using is MySQL.

Comment: I'm just trying doing this in both mysql and sqlite hoping that it maybe the same as this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to Generate `Id's` so you can make you `Union query` as `Sub select` and generate `Id's` in `Outer Query`

`MySQL` does not have any system function like `SQL Server’s row_number ()` to generate the row number for each row. However, it can be generated using the `variable` in the `SELECT statement`

```
SET @row_number:=0;

SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 As Id,
       NAME,
       desc
FROM   (SELECT NAME,desc
        FROM   table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT NAME,desc
        FROM   table2
        UNION ALL
        ........
        ........) A 
Order by NAME -- Change the column in Order by in which order you want to create New ID's
```

Comment: How can I do it using SQLite?

Comment: @Ace123 - Sorry am not sure about `SQLite`, Btw you said you are using `MySql`

Comment: Yes. I'm just trying to use both MySql and SQLite.

Comment: @Ace123 - Cool, check out gordan Linoff's answer

Answer (score 0):

In MySql, you can simulate the `row_number()` function of Sql Server and Oracle using a mutating variable hack:

```
set @rownum := 0;
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS` row_number`, `name`, `desc`
FROM
(
  SELECT `name`, `desc` FROM table1
  UNION 
  SELECT `name`, `desc` FROM table2
) AS x;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac3137/3)

Comment: How can I do it using SQLite?